# Function type using typescript

Tags: function, typescript

Why do I have to cast function into `Function` type to be able to access `apply` and other members?

```
var a: Function = () => {};
a.apply(); // works

var a = () => {};
a.apply(); // does not work
```

How should I do it with these functions?:

```
function a(){}
a.apply(); // does not work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the "this" argument to the `apply` function, it seems to work either way:

```
var a = () => {};
a.apply(null);

var b: Function = () => {};
b.apply(null);
```

Comment: Interesting. It works but the intellisense for `apply` does not work. Do you observe the same and is it not a bug?

Comment: I think this is deliberate. It doesn't suggest `apply` in the intellisense list, but if you type `apply(` it is aware of it and hints at the required arguments. I can't speak on behalf of the TypeScript team - but I think this could be deliberate. The same is true of `call`.